How can Bytes Array be handled successfully in iOS using Codename One
I am working on a app that uses SQLite. It encrypts and decrypts SQLite database using FilesCipher class in this answer
The app also saves images as byte[] in SQLite database. Images column has BLOB data type.
All these works as expected in Simulator & Android devices but NONE of these works in iOS device. I built these apps using build server.
When I use SQLite database WITHOUT encrypting it using FilesCipher class above, images are saved as expected in Simulator & Android but they are NOT saved in iOS device.
When I use SQLite database which is encrypted using FilesCipher class above, I can successfully decrypt and read records in database in Simulator & Android but in iOS it throws the following error ONLY.
java.io.IOException: SQL error in step.  Code: 10

I catched this error and stacktrace using the following code
    try {      



    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.p("Error " + e + "\n" + getErrorInfo(e));
       //save this error log to a shareable text file
    }

    public String getErrorInfo(Exception error) {
        StringBuilder sbError = new StringBuilder();
        StackTraceElement[] errorArr = error.getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement value : errorArr) {
            sbError.append("at ").append(value).append("\n");
        }
        return sbError.toString();
    }

I created images table with the following query
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pictures ( id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, image BLOB)

Then inserted image with the following code
EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.create(image);
byte[] imageData = encodedImage.getImageData();
String query = "INSERT INTO pictures (image) VALUES (?)";
db.execute(query, imageData);

No error is thrown when inserting in iOS.
Note: FilesCipher encryptes & decrypts bytes[] and images are saved as bytes[]. That is, bytes[] is used in both cases.
How can both cases work in iOS as they are working in Simulator & Android?

can you add the stacktrace, and also the part of your code it is pointing to with a bit "surrounding" stuff?

This is the only exception even in stacktrace java.io.IOException: SQL error in step.  Code: 10

@cyberbrain I have added a code snippet of how I caught this exception and stacktrace

This API doesn't work well on iOS. I'm not aware of a workaround other than just encoding a string to the DB.

Saving images as Base64 String works even in iOS now. But in iOS,  images are too big even after compressing them using EncodedImage. I have open this question about this

We generally recommend saving these as files and including reference to the file from the DB. This is also more efficient but obviously would be a problem if you want everything to reside in one file.

Yes, saving images in files is the recommended way. But in this case the requirement is that they must be store in DB where they will be more secure since DB is encrypted.

Can images be saved as Blob as in [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefblob.html#:~:text=A%20BLOB%20(binary%20large%20object,do%20not%20hold%20character%20data.)

Or this discussion where it's possible to save them as ByteArrayInputStream? I tried saving them as ByteArrayInputStream but they were inserted as null even in Simulator

You can encrypt the individual files too. That's not a problem. As I mentioned on Sept. 9th this isn't supported on our iOS implementation.

Main database file encrypted using FilesCipher class above can't be read or written into until it's decrypted first.
I was decrypting and writing decrypted bytes[] to the same main database file, execute queries in 1 request then after the request is successful or not, using } finally {} block I encrypt the main database file to keep it encrypted.This idea of encrypting & decrypting the same file works in Simulator & Android but fails in iOS.
Seems there might be a problem in iOS when decrypting, reading & encrypting the same file.
I did the following for this to work in all platforms including iOS.

Decrypt main database which returns a decrypted byte[]

Create a temp database and write this decrypted byte[] into it.

Close main database to avoid GC warnings in iOS

Set this temp database as the database to use

Delete main database file

Execute requested query or queries like save records in temp database

Encrypt this temp database which returns encrypted byte[]

Create main database file then write this encrypted byte[] to this newly created main database.

Close the temp database to avoid GC warnings in iOS

Set this new main database as the database to use.

Delete the temp database file.


Repeat these steps for every request.
To enhance performance, if a class or a fuction is executing multiple different queries, the temp database should be reused until all queries have been executed then finally go to steps 7, 8, 9, 10 & 11
